# How to know the validity of a vault token that is being used for connecting to vault?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

Currently, I am connecting to a corporate vault service where I am using a vault token and passing it through below header in my spring cloud config service where properties of all microservices are kept.

```
curl -X "GET" "http://localhost:8080/my-client-microservice/dev" -H "X-Config-Token: s.myvaulttoken"
```

where **http://localhost:8080** is my spring cloud config service and **s.myvaulttoken** is my vault token. This is working absolutely fine.

I want to know the validity of this token. What I have read the documentation that token can be of two type: service or batch. I want to know whether this token can be used infinitely (as root tokens validity is infinite).

[image]

Since the client microservices require the vault token, I want to figure out the way to know the validity of a token. Can you guys help me to tell more about this?

I followed this link: https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/getting-started/authentication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Every non-root token has a time-to-live (TTL) associated with it.](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/tokens/#token-time-to-live-periodic-tokens-and-explicit-max-ttls)

For example:

- with a root token, the ttl is 0

  ```
  vault token lookup -format json  | jq .data.ttl
  0
  ```
- with a regular user, the ttl is non-zero

  ```
  VAULT_TOKEN=$(vault token create -policy default -field token) vault token 
  lookup -format json | jq .data.ttl
  2764799
  ```

This check is possible through the [API](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/token/index.html#lookup-a-token) as well.